base-content color not working on daisyui laravel project
 **<a href="" className='text-center main border-2 border-base-100 w-4/5 m-auto p-2 rounded-xl border-opacity-80 bg-inherit transition duration-200 ease-in-out bg-gradient-to-r from-base-300 to-base-100 hover:opacity-80 text-gray-200 '>{buttonName}</a>**
this is the result went the background color doesn't have base-content color
The background color should be base-content color, but on my display, the background color doesn't have base-content color
I tried to reinstall daisyui, and update the npm. I expecting the base-content color to match the daisyui settings and run as it should
